# Light not rendering at all

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, lighting

*Disclaimer: complete beginner to blender.

So i'm trying to render some text, but when I add a point light my render ignores it (on both cycles and eevee). I gave my text glossy material, and my point light is at 3000W and close enough to the text that it should show up pretty well. What am I doing wrong?

*Additional detail I thought may be important: light doesn't show any nodes in compositor, but other than that I believe my light's properties are correct.

Here's my blend file: [image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi Skloggy, welcome to SE. Being a complete beginner is totally ok - but...we need some basic informations what you did and we don't have those. Since you are a beginner i would recommend providing your blend file, so we don't have to ask you or guess around what might be the reason and there could be 10+ reasons for this. You can provide your blend file by opening this: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.

Comment: Are you sure that your lights are enabled for render (check the Outliner)